# Unable to get User Credentials (Windows Authentication)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, authentication, iis

Here is the web config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />

    <authorization>

    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="true" />



  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" >
                    <providers>
                        <clear />
                        <add value="NTLM" />
                    </providers>
                </windowsAuthentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

In the code for the page (trying to see if any of these would work):

```
WindowsIdentity identity = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity;

            string sLoginID = identity.Name.ToString();
            sLoginID = sLoginID.Remove(0, sLoginID.IndexOf('\\') + 1);
            alert.InnerText = User.Identity.Name + "////// " + sLoginID ;
```

Results (Desired is DOMAIN\USERNAME):

```
Anonymous////// NETWORK SERVICE
```

Site is located on iis Server 6.0, Everything is disabled except for identity impersonation and windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get this user due to the identity impersonate parameter.
Change the parameter to

```
identity impersonate=false
```

And check if you got the account

Comment: Hi, I did what you said but I still see:
Anonymous////// NETWORK SERVICE

Comment: Did you restart your IIS service after the modification? Try setting the parameters directly in IIS config and you will generate your web.config after, once you got all the good parameters

Comment: Did you try to use "User.Identity.Name" instead of LogonUserIdentity?

Comment: Still returning : Anonymous////// NETWORK SERVICE. For some reason I just can't get it to use the user's credentials instead of the server's.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowsIdentity identity = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity;

    string sLoginID = identity.Name.ToString();
    TextBox1.Text = sLoginID;
}
```

IIS Settings:

- Anonymous Authentication - Disabled
- ASP.NET Imprsonation - Disabled
- Forms Authentication - Disabled
- Windows Authentication -Disabled

Granted I am running 7.5.

Screenshot (running on IIS and not through VS):

[image]

Comment: oh, and after each change I was restarting website, just in case (it is Microsoft after all) :)

Comment: I copied all of your settings and I am still recieving the same erroneous result. :(